# Abstracting functions / avoiding repetition in functions

Tags: refactoring, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I need some advice on abstracting the `find` and `check-callback` functions. The code works fine, but it seems that there is a lot of unnecessary repetition. Is there a more elegant way to re-write them?

```
;; Model
(define-struct contact (name phone))
(define phonebook (list (make-contact 'adam 5551212)
                        (make-contact 'brian 5552323)
                        (make-contact 'chris 5558888)))

;; find: (string->symbol, string->number) item (listof items) -> symbol/number/false
(define (find type item pb)
  (cond
    [(empty? pb) false]
    [(equal? (string->symbol item) (contact-name (first pb))) (contact-phone (first pb))]
    [(equal? (string->number item) (contact-phone (first pb))) (contact-name (first pb))]
    [else (find type item (rest pb))]))

;; Controller
(define (check-callback b)
  (cond
    [(number? (find string->symbol (text-contents a-text-field) phonebook))
     (draw-message a-msg (number->string (find string->symbol (text-contents a-text-field) phonebook)))]
    [(symbol? (find string->number (text-contents a-text-field) phonebook))
     (draw-message a-msg (symbol->string (find string->number (text-contents a-text-field) phonebook)))]
    [else (draw-message a-msg "Not found")]))


;; View
(define a-text-field
  (make-text "Enter a name or phone number"))

(define a-msg
  (make-message ""))

(define a-button
  (make-button "Search" check-callback))

(create-window
 (list (list a-text-field)
       (list a-button)
       (list a-msg)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `type` variable is not used, I omitted it from the code and made some refactoring:

```
;; find
(define (find item pb)
  (let* ((first-pb (first pb))
         (name (contact-name first-pb))
         (phone (contact-phone first-pb)))
    (cond
      [(empty? pb) #f]
      [(equal? (string->symbol item) name) phone]
      [(equal? (string->number item) phone) name]
      [else (find item (rest pb))])))

;; Controller
(define (check-callback pb)
  (let ((res (find (text-contents a-text-field) pb)))
    (draw-message a-msg
                  (cond
                    [(number? res) (number->string res)]
                    [(symbol? res) (symbol->string res)]
                    [else "Not found"]))))
```

Or you could just convert your name and phone to string at once:

```
;; find
(define (find item pb)
  (let* ((first-pb (first pb))
         (name (contact-name first-pb))
         (phone (contact-phone first-pb)))
    (cond
      [(empty? pb) #f]
      [(equal? (string->symbol item) name) (number->string phone)]
      [(equal? (string->number item) phone) (symbol->string name)]
      [else (find item (rest pb))])))

;; Controller
(define (check-callback pb)
  (let ((res (find (text-contents a-text-field) pb)))
    (draw-message a-msg
                  (if (res)
                    res
                    "Not found"))))
```

Comment: @Greenhorn. The remaining complexity is a result of your decision to store name as symbol and phone as number. Storing both as string would offer the oportunity to make this dramatically simpler, as all of the phonebook fields could be treated generically. Plus in practice phone numbers aren't really numbers, they're strings. Even if you had one or two fields that shouldn't be stored as strings, you could provide a way to convert them to string (like you already need to convert from string, for user input). Then your code to test for equality and display to the view could use that to-string.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Greg. This was another exercise problem from the book I'm using to learn Scheme/Racket, so I'm afraid I don't have any choice in the data types. But I shall bear your advice in mind when tackling problems in the real world. Best wishes.

Comment: @Greenhorn: Ah sorry then probably best to keep working through HtDP as-intended. What it's trying to teach you at each stage, is also of real-world value.